# Child Window Reading Parent Windows in HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, parent-child

I have a parent window opening a child window through window.open. The parent window is on http www.abc.com and the child window is opened on http www.abc.com as well. I have a Javascript file on the parent window that the child window looks at to communicate. When the parent window is on http www.abc.com, both windows are communicating fine. However, when the parent window is on https://secured.abc.com, the child window has issues communicating with the file on the parent window.

Can someone suggest why this is happening?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because non-ssl windows cannot communicate with ssl windows for obvious security concerns.  The entire reason for an ssl window is to encrypt/protect the client data transactions.  If it were possible to reference the windowDOM from a non-secured space that security would be completely compromised.